# Is the Find utility standard on all linux servers?

Tags: linux

Is the Find utility standard on all linux servers? Like Sed and Grep?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is standard.

I've never seen one which didn't have it by default. It's usually in the `findutils` package.

Comment: but specifically the gnu findutils package?

Comment: I never ran into any GNU/Linux or BSD installation which did not have a version of find.

Comment: All GNU/Linux systems will have the GNU findutils package. If they don't have the GNU packages they are not GNU/Linux.